# Smooth contours detection from texture in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, contour, smoothing, sobel

I would like to generate smooth (consitent width and continuous) contours from textures such as the following one:

[image]

I currently run a shader that does very basic edge detection and end up with the following results:

```
void main(void) {

  vec2 texCoord = vec2(((vProjectedCoords.x / vProjectedCoords.w) + 1.0 ) / 2.0,
            ((vProjectedCoords.y / vProjectedCoords.w) + 1.0 ) / 2.0 );

  float borderWidth = uWidth; // in px
  float step_u = borderWidth * 1.0 / uCanvasWidth;
  float step_v = borderWidth * 1.0 / uCanvasHeight;

  vec4 centerPixel = texture2D(uTextureFilled, texCoord);
  vec4 rightPixel  = texture2D(uTextureFilled, texCoord + vec2(step_u, 0.0));
  vec4 bottomPixel = texture2D(uTextureFilled, texCoord + vec2(0.0, step_v));
  // now manually compute the derivatives
  float _dFdX = length(rightPixel - centerPixel) / step_u;
  float _dFdY = length(bottomPixel - centerPixel) / step_v;

  gl_FragColor.r = max(max(centerPixel.r, rightPixel.r), bottomPixel.r);
  gl_FragColor.g = max(max(centerPixel.g, rightPixel.g), bottomPixel.g);
  gl_FragColor.b = max(max(centerPixel.b, rightPixel.b), bottomPixel.b);
  gl_FragColor.a = max(_dFdX, _dFdY);

  return;
```

[image]

Obviously generated contours are not clean but even applying proper sobel filterning didn't enhance that much the results.

I'd like to get almost pixel perfect contours, and ideally also ignore the noise from the input texture if possible.

Thanks!

EDIT: probably need to add some smooth steps such as in:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4ssSRl

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example image, you seem to be working with images that have a fixed background color. This can simplify the job. I'm not sure how the second image relates to the first one. Is it a zoomed-in section of the result?

If I understand correctly, what you describe can be achieved through "bleeding" the texture. Here are the steps:

## Noise removal

Add a pre-pass filter which detects non-background color areas smaller than N pixels and eliminates them from the source image. Each texel should:

1. Sample its immediate neighbors. If they are all background, set to background color and exit. If N-1 neighbors are non-background, keep the texel and exit.
2. Sample the next "ring" of neighbors and repeat the process until N-1 non-background neighbors are met or a threshold of "steps" has been met .

There are probably variations of this and other ways to remove noise that can be applied to your case. See https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/3904/is-it-better-to-blur-the-input-or-output-of-an-edge-detection-shader-for-noise-r also.

The smooth step you reference from ShaderToy works directly with procedural line equations which does not apply to your use-case.

## Contour line

The idea is to generate a map of "edge distances" which contains, for each texel, the distance to the nearest non-background texel. Apply the following filter to generate another texture from the source image. For each pixel:

1. If the corresponding texel is non-background, output black and exit.
2. Otherwise, sample texels around the input texel in a region of the appropriate size depending on the desired border size. Output the distance/255 to the nearest non-background texel. If none are found, output white.

The final processing step will work with both textures to add a contour line. For each pixel:

1. Fetch (or sample using nearest texture filtering) the corresponding "edge distance" image texel.
2. If "edge distance" == 0, fetch and output the corresponding texel from the source image as-is.
3. If "edge distance" == 1.0, output the background color (or the corresponding texel from the source image).
4. Else, this is a border! Multiply by 255 to get the distance to the nearest non-background texel. Output the border color if the distance is smaller than the desired border size. For best results, use `smoothstep` to generate a smooth outline instead of having a hard border cut-off.

## Optimizing performance

There are many possible optimization areas for the whole process. Among others, smart usage of compute shaders and shared memory could significantly reduce the memory bandwidth usage.